# Using Raster layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Always when working with raster layers errors happen. Can´t warp (reproject) layer, or extract contour, for example.
I have unistall Qgis and install back several times in different ways, but didn´t work. 
I work with MacBook. This is an example of one of the errors:

> The following layers were not correctly
>   generated.
>
> - /var/folders/0z/1728_nfx30j9x0vgs79sb9zr0000gn/T/processing_b2c1d0382bbe42b9936283783605c8a7/840b94611d8347b2936535f235e21e98/OUTPUT.tif
> - /var/folders/0z/1728_nfx30j9x0vgs79sb9zr0000gn/T/processing_b2c1d0382bbe42b9936283783605c8a7/a410e5fa0c8444c88370c60c91b55fff/OUTPUT.tif
>
> You
>   can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more
>   information about the execution of the algorithm.

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! If you can provide some additional details about your question it will help other members provide useful answers. For example, what are the inputs you are using, perhaps shown in a screenshot? Also, what version of QGIS are you running? This intro page has suggestions on how to write good questions: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please also check the log messages panel, and update your question with any log messages.